# How do I run logical 'xnor' across a column in a multi-dimensional array (linq or simple algorithm)?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, linq, logical-and

Currently, I have an array of *possibilities*, and I am looking to calculate the *facts* (logical XNOR) based on that list of *possibilities*.

```
var possibilities = new[] {
    new[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    new[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
}
```

I am trying to convert that into a boolean array of XNOR (all values equal)

Expected Result:

```
[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
```

The number of possibilities is 1 .. n.  Another example would be:

```
var possibilities = new[] {
    new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
    new[] {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
}
```

Where result would be:

```
[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]
```

My original approach was to start building nested loops and iterating over each possibility, grabbing the index and comparing it, however that seemed very 'hackish', and I believe there is a simpler (better) way of handling it via LINQ (however I do not know LINQ well enough to write it) or an algorithm that doesn't require ugly nested loops.

**Edit #1: Incorrect 'logic' term used**

As mentioned in the answer below, the correct logic was not in fact AND rather XNOR (where all the columns are equal).  AND would, in fact, produce 0 where all the columns were 0 when I was (as noted above), was really looking for a result of 1 (or true) if all the values were equal.

Comment: Is the size of each possibility fixed?  e.g. you show 8 in each of your examples above.

Comment: @MikeH Ah, yes, the size is fixed, in that every row of possibilities will be the same length (however they could be different lengths in different execution contexts).  But always the length of each possibility will be the same in a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int size = possibilities[0].Length;
int i = 0;
var a = possibilities.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => i++ % size)
              .Select(x => x.Any(z => z == 0) ? 0 : 1);
```

And Using loops:

```
int j = 0, size = possibilities[0].Length;
int[] result = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{ 
     for (j = 0; j < possibilities.Length; j++)
         if (possibilities[j][i] == 0) { result[i] = 0; break; }
     if (j == possibilities.Length) result [i] = 1;
}
```

XNOR:

```
int i = 0;
var a = possibilities.SelectMany(x => x).GroupBy(x => i++ % size)
            .Select(x => x.All(z => z == 0) || x.All(z => z == 1) ? 1 : 0);
```

XNOR with loops:

```
int size = possibilities[0].Length;
int[] result = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{ 
     int q = possibilities[0][i];
     for (j = 1; j < possibilities.Length; j++)
         if (possibilities[j][i] != q) { result[i] = 0; break; }
     if (j == possibilities.Length) result[i] = 1;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BiBiAs)

Comment: I knew there was a cleaner way to do it in LINQ.  And now that I have that, I can break it down and learn LINQ at the same time.

Comment: @AaronMurray glad it helped

Comment: +1 for the loops addition as well, I know/hear LINQ has some performance hits, in my case I suspect its not a problem, the possibilities datasets are relatively small, however future projects may require a non-linq solution.

Comment: @AaronMurray Thanks, in most cases performance difference is not noticeable, however in most cases linq turns a very complex code into a very simple one-liner

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the zip extension. But you need to use aggregate to handle more than two. The only discrepancy is the three zeros you have a result of 1. The and operator (&) will be zero.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var possibilities = new[]
        {
            new[] {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            new[] {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}
        };
        //[ 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0 ]
        var result = possibilities.Aggregate((f, s) => f.Zip(s, (fi, si) => fi & si).ToArray());
        var possibilities2 = new[]
        {
            new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
            new[] {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
        };
        //[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ]
        var result2 = possibilities2.Aggregate((f, s) => f.Zip(s, (fi, si) => fi & si).ToArray());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Ah ha! you are correct, the logic operator I *SHOULD* have been citing is XNOR (where all values in the collection are equal), in an AND scenario 0 & 0 is in fact 0, where (XNOR) a == b == n ? 1 : 0

Comment: OIC... Then this won't work as you compare two arrays at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the response none the less, as the OP used an incorrect logic term which caused confusion, I have updated the question for clarity.

Comment: @clayton re: Better answer (comment deleted), I just saw Askan's answer first (somehow because you actually answered first), and I tested it and it worked :)  I did upvote you as well because your answer was helpful and gives me more to research now too, it is appreciated

Comment: @AaronMurray Yes I see it is better in the current context. I didn't want to come off as super salty. I shouldn't have said anything.

Comment: nah, not at all, furthermore, I did notice that someone else had changed my original question showing the second example result as AND and when I was testing and comparing I completely  missed that Ashkan's first answer (while correct) didn't work on the XNOR logic properly, I corrected the change back to XNOR as well :)  Seems odd that people editing questions would edit the actual question rather than just formatting fixes. (hah, I just looked and Ashkan edited it :) )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using only 1 loop to carry the index of the element in question...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var possibilities = new[] {
        new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        new[] {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
        new[] {0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}
    };

    IList<int> output = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < possibilities[0].Length; i++)
    {
         output.Add(possibilities.All(x => x.ElementAt(i) == possibilities[0][i]) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", output));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Returns [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0] for first example.
Returns [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] for second example.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple implementation here is to say something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < list1.Count(); i++){
list3[i] = list1[i] && list2[i]
}
```

If you must to this with linq, you could import the MoreLinq library and then combine .interleave with .batch

https://morelinq.github.io/2.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Interleave__1.htm
http://www.toplinestrategies.com/blogs/application-development/grouping-data-morelinq-batch-extension-method
https://github.com/morelinq

Comment: Although Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani's linq is way more elegant than this

Comment: Also, the OP states: "The number of possibilities is 1 .. n". Your algorithm doesn't work for an arbitrary number of lists.